# Filter logs PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm working on a code on the PHP that reads the line from a log and echo to the user based on the needed date.

Here's my code,

```
<?php
$x=0;

$filestring= file_get_contents( "argh.txt" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
$filearray = explode("/n", $filestring);

    while (list($var,$val) = each($filearray)) {
        print "$val <br/>";
        ++$x;
    }
?>
```

This is my output:

```
00:31:32,subID=1,SC=22919,Ctnt=Talk
00:31:45,subID=1,SC=22919,Ctnt=ON
00:31:45,subID=2,SC=22919,Ctnt=INVITE 0196966467
00:31:45,subID=1,SC=22919,Ctnt=Alright
00:31:45,subID=2,SC=22919,Ctnt=INVITE 0146966467
00:31:45,subID=2,SC=22919,Ctnt=INVITE 0166966467
```

I want the results to show based on the subID and Ctnt= Invite ( filtering and showing the results , sub id could be anything but Ctnt has to filter based on invite 0*) 
Results ,
Such as :
subID=1, Ctnt=

Comment: Well did you try anything at all?

Comment: @dev0, Yes. I've tried explode, trim, map_array but still the logic just isn't there. I actually wrote this code but in this part I'm stuck. Even I tried filter php function , no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something from the code you have provided,try it out:

```
<?php
$x=0;
$filter_subID = $_POST['subID'];
$filter_Ctnt = $_POST['Ctnt'];

$filestring= file_get_contents( "argh.txt" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
$filearray = explode("/n", $filestring);

    while (list($var,$val) = each($filearray)) {
        $match_sub = false;
        $match_ctnt = false;
        $csv = explode(',',$val);
        unset($csv[0]);
        $csv = array_values($csv);
        foreach($csv as $logvals){
            list($field,$value) = explode('=',$logvals);
            if(trim($field) == 'subID' && trim($value) == $filter_subID){
                $match_sub = true;
            }
            if(trim($field) == 'Ctnt' && trim($value) == $filter_Ctnt){
                $match_ctnt = true;
            }
        }
        if($match_sub && $match_ctnt) print "$val <br/>";
        ++$x;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ty Dominick, but after running the code I just got blank output.

Comment: But when i remove this line if($match_sub && $match_ctnt) , I get back the whole log content.

Comment: how do you run your php file? if by browser you have to send post variables subID and Ctnt

Comment: By browser, but the log varies from subID to Ctnt, i usually get error even I put a * to fill in all the values.. I could find an aspect to commit to post function . Any idea mate?

Comment: the code I gave you doesn't support using wildcard characters such as *, by the terms you are speaking I suggest you study the basics first.

Comment: Another question , if you may.
Instead of using post , could i just pass string to subID and ctnt will be able to work it out?

Comment: if you dont want to use post you can replace the $_POST to $_GET,then run your code using http:/localhost/file.php?subID=1&Ctnt=SAMPLE